# Spring OAuth2 - There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter

Tags: spring-security, access-token, spring-security-oauth2

We have an application which is using `spring-security-oauth2:1.0`. I was trying to change it to a newer version, `spring-security-oauth2:2.0.7.RELEASE`. Some classes were removed, some package structure is changed, I managed to sort out all those things and I was able to start the server without any issue. But I am facing a strange issue here.

With `OAuth2 - 1.0 version`, when the user logs in we used to do a `GET` request on `/oauth/token`, For example :

> http://localhost:8080/echo/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=ws&client_secret=secret&scope=read,write&username=john@abc.com&password=password123

and It used to work just fine.

When I try the same thing, First of all I am not able to make a `GET` request because of the logic in [TokenEndPoint.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/TokenEndpoint.java)

```
private Set<HttpMethod> allowedRequestMethods = new HashSet<HttpMethod>(Arrays.asList(HttpMethod.POST));

@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/token", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken> getAccessToken(Principal principal, @RequestParam
Map<String, String> parameters) throws HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException {
    if (!allowedRequestMethods.contains(HttpMethod.GET)) {
        throw new HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException("GET");
    }
    return postAccessToken(principal, parameters);
}
```

I have tried to make a `POST` request same as above URL, but I get `InsufficientAuthenticationException` with the error message

> There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter

This is because of the following `POST` request controller in `TokenEndpoint.java`. When I debug, I see that `principal` is null.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/token", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken> postAccessToken(Principal principal, @RequestParam
    Map<String, String> parameters) throws HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException {
        //principal is null here
        if (!(principal instanceof Authentication)) {
            throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException(
                    "There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter.");
        }
     .............
 }
```

I have an authentication filter and it worked well when I used `version 1.0`. This is the relevant prats of my config:

```
    <authentication-manager xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService"/>
    </authentication-manager>

   <bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.hcl.nc.service.UserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg><ref bean="sessionFactory" /></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

I always thought that the request will be authenticated by `authentication-provider` and goes to `token-endpoint` but that does not seem to be the correct flow. After debugging the application with `version 2.0.7`, now I really doubt my understanding about the flow.

**Could somebody please explain why it worked in previous version and why it's not working now?**

**Do I have do to something different to get a OAuth token??**

**NOTE**: I have already checked these questions : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451245/basic-authentication-filter-and-authentication-entry-point-not-actually-used-fro), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27310668/spring-oauth2-insufficientauthenticationexception), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140020/understanding-oauth2-client-credentials-flow). But I was not able to find the correct solution.

Comment: Have you find the answer ? I encounter with the same question and find no answers here.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know the previous version, but I know a bit about 2.0.7.

I suspect your problem is that your TokenEndpoint security tries to authenticate your *clients* against your *user* service.

The TokenEndpoint is protected by a `BasicAuthenticationFilter`. By default this filter would use an `AuthenticationManager` instance, which itself holds an `AuthenticationProvider`, which itself depends on an instance of `UserDetailsService`.
The trick is that this particular instance of `UserDetailsService` must be **client** based, not **user** based : that's why there is a `ClientDetailsUserDetailsService`, which adapts `ClientDetailsService` to `UserDetailsService`.

Normally all this stuff is already done by default when you use the framework's configuration classes `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`, `@EnableAuthorizationServer`, etc..

Comment: so how does all this stuff get done when I use xml configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and my application.yml had this line:

```
servlet:
    path: /auth
```

so the token address was: `/auth/oauth/token`

I remove the path from application.yml so the token path became:

`/oauth/token`

And everything works fine.

I hope this help

Comment: Though this is not a solution I was looking for, but gave me direction and rootcause of the exception. If anyone knows how to work with oauth and servlet context, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems of the following error, can be that authentication was not performed. I have encountered this problem with older implementation of Spring.

verify that:

TokenEndpoint -> postAccessToken method. Check if Principal is not null. If it is null it means that Basic Authroziation was not performed.

One of the solution to add filter was to use:

```
@Configuration
public class FilterChainInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

More information about AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer can be found in Spring docs

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be because of opening all requests. You should remove it.

```
 @Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/**");
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer for me. Anyone who has this issue should check the implementation of the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter first. See if you open the URL like "/oauth/token" or "/oauth/**" or "/**", in the function above. Doing so, makes all the oauth end points expose to outside without security checks, which defeat the purpose of Spring Security Oauth. So, make your URL exclusion explicit and do not expose oauth endpoints should fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i found this config:

**security.allowFormAuthenticationForClients(); // here**

then post this
    http://localhost:8081/sso/oauth/token?client_id=unity-client&client_secret=unity&grant_type=authorization_code&code=Yk4Sum&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8082/sso-demo/passport/login

its works for me, try it

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class Oauth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Oauth2Config.class);

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.allowFormAuthenticationForClients(); // here 
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception { // @formatter:off
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("unity-client")
                .secret("unity")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "password", "client_credentials", "implicit", "refresh_token")
                .scopes("foo", "read", "write")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600) // 1 hour
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(2592000) // 30 days
        ;
    } // @formatter:on

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am following this tutorial - Practical Guide to Building an API Back End with Spring Boot'. See https://www.infoq.com/minibooks/spring-boot-building-api-backend  , But with the latest SpringBoot Version(2.7)

and I run into this problem:

`org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter. at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(TokenEndpoint.java:91) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:na]`

My solution/fix was to annotate `WebSecurityGlobalConfig` with `@EnableWebSecurity` because in the original course this annotation was missing.
So adding this annotaiton has fixed the error for me.